# What swing component use to display photo with description

Tags: java, swing

I am quite new to java swing.

I want to do a class Photo that displays some thing like this:

## Title

Here goes a photograph

Here goes a description

I do not know if I should make my class Photo extends JPanel or what.
Also I do not know if what layout to use.

If there was a chance that I could use HTML to display the title, image and description it would be great.

Thanks for any advice.

NOTE: From another class (a JFrame) i will add this Photo class.

Comment: You could try a JList, or you could try a grid of JLabels held in a JPanel using a GridLayout, but at least try something anything **before** coming here. Seriously.

Comment: *"If there was a chance that I could use HTML to display the title, image and description it would be great."*  It's great.

Comment: You can get that done by just using jLabels, labels can accept html. Just use <html></html> inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should develope it yourself if you want it to be pure swing. See and test the following sample code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Photo extends JPanel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String title;
    private ImageIcon image;
    private String description;

    private JLabel titleLabel;
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    private JLabel descLabel;

    public Photo(String title, ImageIcon image, String description) {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5));
        //
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredSoftBevelBorder());
        //
        this.title = title; 
        this.titleLabel = new JLabel(title);
        Font f = this.titleLabel.getFont();
        f = f.deriveFont(Font.BOLD);
        f = f.deriveFont(18f);
        this.titleLabel.setFont(f);
        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        northPanel.add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //
        this.image = image;
        this.imageLabel = new JLabel(image);
        this.add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //
        this.description = description;
        this.descLabel = new JLabel(description);
        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        southPanel.add(descLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
        repaint();
    }

    public ImageIcon getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(ImageIcon image) {
        this.image = image;
        repaint();
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

`main` to use the above sample code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class PhotoTest {
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 300;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        f.setBounds(dim.width/2-FRAME_WIDTH/2, dim.height/2-FRAME_HEIGHT/2, FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //
        URL url = new URL("http://www.archisevilla.org/wp-content/themes/archisevilla/images/loading.gif");
        //URL url = Photo.class.getResource("a.jpg"); // Use this if your image is near your 
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(url);
        Photo photo = new Photo("Title", image, "Sample of a photo component!");
        f.add(photo);
        //
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this Java Swing application as a radio button example, but it displays images with a title and description, so it would do what you want.  The images come from the Internet, so you can run the code without any modifications, although some of the images may disappear over time.

Here's a screen shot of the GUI.

[image: Image Display GUI]

1. The image information is kept in a List.  The ImageInformation class is a model class.
2. The image panel is created in a method, not a class.  You could pull the method into a class, but it's simple enough for a method.

And here's the code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class ImageDisplay implements Runnable {

    private ItemListener listener;

    private JFrame frame;

    private JLabel titleLabel;
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    private JLabel descriptionLabel;

    private List<ImageInformation> images;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ImageDisplay());
    }

    public ImageDisplay() {
        this.images = setImageInformation();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Image Display");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createControlPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(createImagePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createImagePanel() {
        JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel();
        imagePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        ImageInformation defaultImageInformation = images.get(0);

        titleLabel = new JLabel(defaultImageInformation.getTitle());
        titleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        imagePanel.add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
                defaultImageInformation.getImage()));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(imageLabel);
        imagePanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        descriptionLabel = new JLabel(defaultImageInformation.getDescription());
        descriptionLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        imagePanel.add(descriptionLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        return imagePanel;
    }

    private JPanel createControlPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Images"));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

        listener = new ImageListener();

        for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
            ImageInformation imageInformation = images.get(i);
            JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton(imageInformation.getTitle());
            if (i == 0) {
                button.setSelected(true);
            }
            button.addItemListener(listener);
            group.add(button);
            panel.add(button);
        }

        return panel;
    }

    private List<ImageInformation> setImageInformation() {
        List<ImageInformation> images = new ArrayList<ImageInformation>();

        // Here, you would get your images
        Image image1 = getImage("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-vfRL5DamWFs/"
                + "T2nn6D_EUfI/AAAAAAAABB8/Kc9Y33qYWJo/s1600/People-Power.jpg");
        Image image2 = getImage("http://www.jeffjonesillustration.com/images/"
                + "illustration/00601-group-of-people.jpg");
        Image image3 = getImage("http://img1.loadtr.com/b-404076-People.jpg");
        Image image4 = getImage("http://www.druginfo.sl.nsw.gov.au/images/teens.jpg");
        Image image5 = getImage("http://www.pesconsulting.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/"
                + "2013/03/kevin-thom-2010-people-collage.jpg");
        Image image6 = getImage("http://www.emcdda.europa.eu/attachements.cfm/"
                + "att_77302_EN_young-people-480px.jpg");

        images.add(new ImageInformation(image1, "Image 1",
                "Image 1 Description"));
        images.add(new ImageInformation(image2, "Image 2",
                "Image 2 Description"));
        images.add(new ImageInformation(image3, "Image 3",
                "Image 3 Description"));
        images.add(new ImageInformation(image4, "Image 4",
                "Image 4 Description"));
        images.add(new ImageInformation(image5, "Image 5",
                "Image 5 Description"));
        images.add(new ImageInformation(image6, "Image 6",
                "Image 6 Description"));

        return images;
    }

    private Image getImage(String fileName) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(new URL(fileName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private ImageInformation getImageInformation(String title) {
        for (ImageInformation imageInformation : images) {
            if (title.equals(imageInformation.getTitle())) {
                return imageInformation;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public class ImageListener implements ItemListener {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
            if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                JRadioButton button = (JRadioButton) event.getItem();
                String labelText = button.getText();
                ImageInformation imageInformation = getImageInformation(labelText);
                if (imageInformation != null) {
                    titleLabel.setText(imageInformation.getTitle());
                    imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imageInformation
                            .getImage()));
                    descriptionLabel.setText(imageInformation.getDescription());
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class ImageInformation {

        private final Image image;

        private final String title;
        private final String description;

        public ImageInformation(Image image, String title, String description) {
            this.image = image;
            this.title = title;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public Image getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

    }
}
```